# why value is printed twice on console?

Tags: reactjs

Am trying to print the value of selected color on browser console,I dont understand why it print twice and how to correct it.

```
const ProductList = () => {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});
  const handleFilters = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const name = e.target.name;
    setFilters({
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
  console.log(filters);
   
  return (
    <Container>
      <Announcement />
      <Navbar />
      <Title>Dresses</Title>
      <FilterContainer>
        <Filter>
          <FilterText>Filter Products:</FilterText>
          <Select name="color" onChange={handleFilters}>
            <Option disabled>color</Option>
            <Option>white</Option>
            <Option>black</Option>
            <Option>red</Option>
            <Option>pink</Option>
            <Option>brown</Option>
            <Option>green</Option>
            <Option>milk</Option>
          </Select>
        </Filter>
      </FilterContainer>
      <Products />
      <Newsletter />
      <Footer />
    </Container>
  );
};
export default ProductList;
```

[![console image][1]][1][1]:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKPHu.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of React Strict Mode code.

```
Remove -> React.StrictMode, from ReactDOM.render code.
```

Will render 2 times on every re-render:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
<App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Will render 1 time:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <>
<App />
  </>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```